# How to add space Address of hyperlink in Java apache

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I have using Java to set hyperlink column in excel at a time file name has contain space in folder name(ex: `Employee Details`) it will return below error.My doubt how to add hyperlink setAddress with space name in folder.

```
File file=new File("/home/suser/Desktop/pathfile/Employee Details /1.pdf")
Hyperlink fileLink = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_FILE);
fileLink.setAddress(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Address of hyperlink must be a valid URI
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFHyperlink.validate(XSSFHyperlink.java:212)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFHyperlink.setAddress(XSSFHyperlink.java:194)
    at com.example.excelapp.ExcelApp.main(ExcelApp.java:83)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 27: /home/user/Desktop/class Name/ExcelApp/
'/home/user/Desktop/pathfile/Employee Details /1.pdf'
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2810)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2983)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3067)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3025)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:577)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFHyperlink.validate(XSSFHyperlink.java:210)
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if a link to a file, a hyperlink always links to a URI. And a URI must be URI encoded. So a space will be encoded `%20`.

Knowing this, I would  work with URIs always if it comes to hyperlinks.

Working Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;

class ExcelCellHyperlink {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

   Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

   File filePDF = new File("/home/axel/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-3.14/Employee Details /1.pdf");
System.out.println(filePDF.toURI().toString());

   //create a cell with a link to absolute file URI
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   Hyperlink fileLink = wb.getCreationHelper().createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_FILE);
   fileLink.setAddress(filePDF.toURI().toString());
   cell.setCellValue("link to absolute file URI");
   cell.setHyperlink(fileLink);

   //create a file with the file path for this Excel file
   File thisExcelFilePath = new File("/home/axel/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-3.14/");
System.out.println(thisExcelFilePath.toURI().toString());
   //create a URI to the PDF file relative to the path of this Excel file
   String relativeURI = thisExcelFilePath.toURI().relativize(filePDF.toURI()).toString();
System.out.println(relativeURI);

   //create a cell with a link to relative file URI
   row = sheet.createRow(2);
   cell = row.createCell(0);
   fileLink = wb.getCreationHelper().createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_FILE);
   fileLink.setAddress(relativeURI);
   cell.setCellValue("link to relative file URI");
   cell.setHyperlink(fileLink);

   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(thisExcelFilePath.getPath() + "/ExcelCellHyperlink.xlsx");
   wb.write(fileOut);
   fileOut.close();

  } catch (IOException ioex) {
    ioex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

This example also shows how to create a hyperlink URI relative to the path of this Excel file. This is more practically since absolute paths will be highly dependent of whether they are reachable from the Excel application.